# Fetch Active User Locations

Tags: laravel

I have below tables with following fields

admins Table

```
 ->id (int)
 ->name (string)
 ->status (boolean)
```

locations Table

```
->id (int)
->name (string
```

)

I have many to many relation between this two tables via pivot table

admin_locations

```
 ->admin_id
 ->location_id
```

My Model

```
Admin.php

public function locations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Location', 'admin_location');
    }

Location.php
    public function admin()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin','admin_location');
    }
```

I want to fetch only admin whose status is 1 along with the relationship. I'm using the above query to fetch admin locations. How can i fetch admin locations where admin status is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
        public function activeAdmin()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin','admin_location')->where('admins.status', true);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. But it's not what i expect.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Model function in your "Location.php" file like this :

```
public function activeAdmins(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin', 'admin_locations', 'location_id', 'admin_id')->where('admins.status', true);
}
```